# Touchscreen isn't recognized on Linux

Tags: linux, touchscreen

Recently I bought a Lenovo Z400 with touchscreen and worked perfectly on the Windows 8 that came with it. The problem is, I can't get to use it on Linux (I'm using Fedora 20).

In my dmesg I get a mention about it, but in my lsusb I can't get anything. I'm not sure which version or model is it.

Well, below is the lsusb's output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:5170 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 06cb:1d10 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

...but I found a mention in dmesg's output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# dmesg | grep -i touch
[    3.811749] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126c00, board id: 2336, fw id: 1214763
[    3.880791] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[    3.911292] usb 3-2: Product: Synaptics Large Touch Screen
[   15.255814] input: SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/input/input9
[   15.255927] hid-rmi 0003:06CB:1D10.0001: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse     [SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Not sure if is needed, but here's the lspci's output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
[root@localhost ~]#
```

xinput doesn't show the device either

```
[root@localhost ~]# xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer            id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
[root@localhost ~]#
```

I also tried a Ubuntu 14.04 livecd, but didn't work nor appeared on lsusb's output.

Comment: Mentions a dell, but the drivers are likely synaptec drivers rather than dell-specific: http://askubuntu.com/questions/398113/make-touchscreen-working-with-ubuntu-13-10-on-dell-xps13

Comment: thanks, @horatio. I've tried the instructions but without luck. I've conveted the .deb package to an .rpm package and got

Transaction check error:
  file / from install of config-usbhid-synaptics-touchscreen-1-2.noarch conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-19.fc20.x86_64

I've extracted the contents and was just a modprobe's confi file and some docs; put them on their paths and restarted; nothing changed.
I edited the original post with xinput's output. my kernel doesn't seems to recognize the device; on that link, Ubuntu had already recognized the touchscreen.